# How to set excel value to datagrid in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, mvvm, datagrid

xmal.c

```
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="337" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="514" Margin="103,39,0,0">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Lecturers}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone_Number}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Excel row and column:

```
Name   Surname   Phone_Number

A        C           123

C        C           124
```

Hi.I got the values ​​in Excel. It comes in the same way. But I couldn't do it when I wanted to set datagrid. How do I set datagrid? The same datagrid row counts with Excel.

```
 **Lecturers.DataSource=cellvalue**
```

this line use set datagrid. But I don't set datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

First create a class which represent your data

```
    public class Lecturer
    {
       public string Name { get; set;}

       public string Surname { get; set;}

       public int Phone_Number { get; set;}
    }
```

Then in your ViewModel, declare an ObservableCollection in which you will be able to store Read objects in it.
An ObservableCollection implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface that will allow your view to be notified of a data change in the ViewModel.

```
[...]

public ObservableCollection<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }

public MyViewModel()
{
  Lecturers = new ObservableCollection<Lecturer>();
}

public void ExtractLecturersFromXlFile(string filePath)
{
 Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
 Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

 Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
 Excel.Range excelrange = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range("A1:C100",Type.Missing);

 // Iterate through datas, fill Lecturer's object and add it to the Observable                 
 // Collection


 // Cleanup  
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

 // Close and release  
 xlWorkbook.Close();
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

 // Quit and release  
 xlApp.Quit();
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

}
```

And in the XAML

```
     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="337" VerticalAlignment="Top"                   Width="514" Margin="103,39,0,0">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lecturers}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone_Number}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```